# Get value of the passed argument to script importing variables from another script

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable

I am trying to export variables from one script to the main script and passing one of the imported variables as argument to the main script.

Here is the script `fruitcolour.sh` having variables only :

```
apple="Red"
mango="Yellow"
orange="Orange"
pear="Green"
```

Here is the main script `GetFruitColour.sh` :

```
#!/bin/bash

source fruitcolour.sh

echo "The colour of " $@ " is " $@ "."
```

For passing `apple` as argument, I want to get the value of variable `apple` i.e. `Red` .

So, When I run `./GetFruitColour.sh apple`

It must give output :: `The colour of apple is Red.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is through indirection -- referring to another variable from the value of the first variable.

To demonstrate:

```
apple="Red"
var="apple"
echo "${!var}"
```

Results in:

```
Red
```

Because bash first takes `!var` to mean the value of the `var` variable, which is then interpreted via `${apple}` and turned into `Red`.

As a result, your GetFruitColour.sh script could look like:

```
#!/bin/bash

source ./fruitcolour.sh

for arg in "$@"
do
  printf 'The colour of %s is %s.\n' "$arg" "${!arg}"
done
```

I've made the path to the sourced script relative instead of bare, to make it clearer where the file is (if the given filename does not contain a slash, shells will search the `$PATH` variable for it, which may surprise you).

I've also [changed `echo` to `printf`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/117549).

The functional change is to use the looping variable `$arg` and the indirect expansion of it to produce the desired values:

```
$ ./GetFruitColour.sh apple mango
The colour of apple is Red.
The colour of mango is Yellow.
```

Do note that there's no error-checking here:

```
$ ./GetFruitColour.sh foo
The colour of foo is .
```

You may find it easier to use an associative array:

```
declare -A fruits='([orange]="Orange" [apple]="Red" [mango]="Yellow" [pear]="Green" )'

for arg in "$@"
do
  if [ "${fruits["$arg"]-unset}" = "unset" ]
  then
    echo "I do not know the color of $arg"
  else
    printf 'The colour of %s is %s.\n' "$arg" "${fruits["$arg"]}"
  fi
done
```

Comment: That's the most concise explanation of `!var` that I've seen.

Comment: It worked great. Thank you for explaining.

Comment: The only point to add: `for arg in "$@"` boils down to mere `for arg`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use an indirect variable reference:

> If the first character of parameter is an exclamation point (!), and parameter is not a nameref, it introduces a level of indirection. Bash uses the value formed by expanding the rest of parameter as the new parameter; this is then expanded and that value is used in the rest of the expansion, rather than the expansion of the original parameter. This is known as indirect expansion.

fruitcolor.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

source fruitcolor.sh

echo "The color of $1 is ${!1}"
```

---

```
$ ./getfruitcolor.sh apple
The color of apple is Red
```